# Trying to build an old release of Azure Api management developer portal version 2.8.0 but getting build errors

Tags: node-modules, azure-api-management, self-hosting, build-error

Unable to build Azure Api management developer portal "v2.8.0". Getting build errors.

Tried building in powershell commandline with different node and npm versions but still unable to resolve node package dependencies and other issues.

Use below to reproduce the build errors:

Azure Api management developer portal v2.8.0(Download from github)

node v20.5.0

npm v10.1.0

Execute below commands on your local windows powershell environment in Admin mode:

npm install --production=false

npm run build

npm start